# Why the entered data failed to be added

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem when I want to enter data in the form of test scores into my website, because the entered score data does not enter the mysql database and an error message appears "Gagal menambahkan nilai" which means the score failed to be added.

This is the controller :

```
<?php

class Nilsemhas extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['nilsemhas']       = $this->nilsemhas_model->tampil_data()->result();
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/header_lec');
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/sidebar_lec');
        $this->load->view('administrator/nilsemhas', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/footer_lec');
    }

    public function detail($id_nilsemhas)
    {
        $data['detail'] = $this->nilsemhas_model->ambil_id_nilsemhas($id_nilsemhas);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/header_lec');
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/sidebar_lec');
        $this->load->view('administrator/nilsemhas_detail',  $data);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/footer_lec');
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        $where = array('id_nilsemhas' => $id);
        $data['nilsemhas'] = $this->nilsemhas_model->edit_data(
            $where,
            'nilsemhas'
        )->result();
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/header_lec');
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/sidebar_lec');
        $this->load->view('administrator/nilsemhas_update', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/footer_lec');
    }

    public function update_aksi()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id_nilsemhas');
        $nilsemhas_1 = $this->input->post('nilsemhas_1');
        $nilsemhas_2 = $this->input->post('nilsemhas_2');
        $nilsemhas_3 = $this->input->post('nilsemhas_3');

        $data = array(
            'nilsemhas_1' => $nilsemhas_1,
            'nilsemhas_2' => $nilsemhas_2,
            'nilsemhas_3' => $nilsemhas_3,
        );

        $this->db->where('id_nilsemhas', $id);
        $this->db->update('nilsemhas', $data);

        if ($this->db->error()['code'] !== 0) {
            $error = $this->db->error();
            $error_message = 'Database Error (' . $error['code'] . '): ' . $error['message'];
            show_error($error_message);
        }

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show"
        role="alert">
        Nilai Seminar Hasil Berhasil Ditambahkan!
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-close" data-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show"
        role="alert">
        Gagal menambahkan nilai!
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-close" data-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>');
        }

        redirect('administrator/nilsemhas');
    }

    public function _rules()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'nilsemhas_1',
            'nilsemhas_1',
            'required',
            ['required' => 'Wajib Diisi!']
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'nilsemhas_2',
            'nilsemhas_2',
            'required',
            ['required' => 'Wajib Diisi!']
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'nilsemhas_3',
            'nilsemhas_3',
            'required',
            ['required' => 'Wajib Diisi!']
        );
    }
}
```

And this is the model :

```
<?php

class Nilsemhas_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function tampil_data()
    {
        $this->db->select('dfsemhas.nama_mhs_semhas, dfsemhas.nim_semhas, dfsemhas.prodi_semhas, dfsemhas.judul_semhas, nilsemhas.id_nilsemhas');
        $this->db->from('nilsemhas');
        $this->db->join('dfsemhas', 'dfsemhas.id_semhas = nilsemhas.id_semhas');
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    public function input_data($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('nilsemhas', $data);
    }

    public function ambil_id_nilsemhas($id_nilsemhas)
    {
        $this->db->select('dfsemhas.nama_mhs_semhas, dfsemhas.nim_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.prodi_semhas, dfsemhas.judul_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.dospem1_semhas, dfsemhas.dospem2_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.dosenuji1_semhas, dfsemhas.dosenuji2_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.komisi_semhas, dfsemhas.tgl_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.waktu_semhas, dfsemhas.tempat_semhas,
                            nilsemhas.*');
        $this->db->from('nilsemhas');
        $this->db->join('dfsemhas', 'dfsemhas.id_semhas = nilsemhas.id_semhas');
        $this->db->where('nilsemhas.id_nilsemhas', $id_nilsemhas);
        $hasil = $this->db->get();

        if ($hasil->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $hasil->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function edit_data($where, $table)
    {
        $this->db->select('nilsemhas.*, dfsemhas.nama_mhs_semhas, dfsemhas.nim_semhas, dfsemhas.prodi_semhas, dfsemhas.judul_semhas, nilsemhas.id_nilsemhas');
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->join('dfsemhas', 'dfsemhas.id_semhas = nilsemhas.id_semhas');
        $this->db->where($where);
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    public function update_data($where, $data, $table)
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->update($table, $data);

        if ($this->db->error()['code'] !== 0) {
            $error = $this->db->error();
            $error_message = 'Database Error (' . $error['code'] . '): ' . $error['message'];
            show_error($error_message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: Your question doesn't specify what you want to enter and which  function are you using for it. Be more specific.

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Your `update($id)` controller method is pointing to the `edit_data($where, $table)` model method, but that is only a `SELECT` query.